# Identify microcontroller (24CC MQRV819.1 1739 on P6901 V2.6 board)

Tags: hardware, integrated-circuit, documentation

I was trying to identify the following integrated circuit (marked with the codes 24CC MQRV819.1 1739).

[image: 24CC MQRV819.1 1739 Microcontroller]

It is mounted on the P6901 V2.6 board of a fingerprint presence recorder.

[image: P6901 V2.6 board]

Given the function of the board and the other components on it I think that it is a microcontroller.

I searched the codes but I didn't find a datasheet or any documentation.
I also searched for a database with the pinouts of the IC to filter it using pin position/number (for example of GND, Vcc, etc...) but I didn't find anything useful.

Could it be a proprietary chip? How can I find more information?

Comment: Did you ever find out what this was? I just opened up an old GT300 dashboard cam which has a very similar chip in it. 24CC MQPY400 1728, but I can't find anything about it online.

Comment: No, I'm quite sure it's a microcontroller, because the other ICs on the board are only memory, clock, sound controllers... I found some IO pins and power supply based on the connection to other components, but I didn't find any additional documentation.